# Disable users to download SVG from website

Tags: reactjs, image, svg

I am using a lot of SVGs on my website. These are custom made Architectural/Art drawings and i would NOT like them to be reused or downloaded. And am looking for an option (if it is actually possible) to disable downloading of all SVGs on my website.

you can see my website on underconstructioncity.com and on the homepage a lot of SVGs

for now i am loading them with an  tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any file transferred to a browser is downloadable, so no you cannot disable it. You can make it a bit more inconvenient by disabling the right-click menu for those images if you want though. You could also convert your svg files to png's if it is the original files themselves you want to protect and not what they portray.

Comment: that is what i taught but using SVGs only for a short time i taught there might be a different solution. Thank you anyway. Disabling right click is ok but it's still not protection as i want it. thank you :) i think i'll have to go with the png.

Answer (score 0):

One problem with having raw SVGs on your page is that the user can click down on them, and then drag them around the screen. I didn't want that on an application I'm working on, so I have covered every SVG with a matching, invisible DIV. And I've transferred my user-interface from the SVGs to the DIVs. You might find this overlay-DIV technique gives you the protection that you want.

Comment: This is nice but yet i think @dockson s solution with disabling right click gives me the similar effect minus the double divs hassle. I'm still thinking of selling these drawings so i'll probably go for PNGs, but i can't help but wonder, if svg is a intellectual property or something like that is it a subject to copyright infrigment laws?